# Compare type to instance

Tags: c#

How can I compare a type to an instance?

This is what I've tried but it does not compile

Heres the error:

> Error 242 The type or namespace name 'type' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public static Control GetParentControl(this Control c, Type type)
{
            Control p = c.Parent;

            while (p != null && !(p is type)) 
            {
                p = p.Parent; 
            }

            return p; 
        }
```

Comment: `type == p.GetType()`

Try comparing type like that and see if that works

Comment: "It does not compile", note that the compiler usually tells you what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use templates.

```
 PreBooking pb = GetParent<PreBooking>.Get(this) as PreBooking; 



  public class GetParent<T>
    {
        public static object Get(Control c)
        {
            Control p = c.Parent;
            while (p != null && !(p is T))
            {
                p = p.Parent;
            }
            return p;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

replace

```
while (p != null && !(p is type))
```

with

```
while (p != null && !(p.GetType() == type))
```

the `is` operator can only be used with a type name, not a variable of the type `Type`. You need to call [`GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) on the variable to get its type and compare it with the type variable.